# Problem with arrow tips drawn twice in tikz

Tags: tikz-arrows

I'm trying to draw a simple graph with arrows. But when I compile my file, latex draws 2 tips, one at the beginning of the arrow, the other at the end, like so:

[image: example]

here is the code I used :

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz,pgf}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,tikzmark,shapes,decorations.pathmorphing,decorations.pathreplacing,decorations.text,decorations,shapes.symbols,arrows,positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node (heure) {Heures};
  \node[right=2cm of heure] (minute) {Minutes};
  \node[right=2cm of minute] (seconde) {Secondes};
  \draw[-stealth] (heure.north) edge[bend left] node[midway,above] {\times 60} (minute.north);
  \draw[-stealth] (minute.north) edge[bend left] node[midway,above] {\times 60} (seconde.north);
  \path[-stealth] (minute.south) edge[bend left] node[midway,below] {\times 60} (heure.south);
  \draw[-stealth] (seconde.south) edge[bend left] node[midway,below] {\times 60} (minute.south);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Compiled with lualatex on texlive2016. Can someone tell me what the problem is? 
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main problem is that you are using `edge` instead of `to`.  `edge` creates an extra path.  In addition your labels should be in math mode, and it would help to shorten a couple of the arrows.  I have removed unnecessary libraries for this example, but the code also works with all the libraries you use.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node (heure) {Heures};
  \node[right=2cm of heure] (minute) {Minutes};
  \node[right=2cm of minute] (seconde) {Secondes};
  \draw[-stealth,shorten >= 2pt] (heure.north) to[bend left] node[midway,above] {$\times 60$} (minute.north);
  \draw[-stealth] (minute.north) to[bend left] node[midway,above] {$\times 60$} (seconde.north);
  \draw[-stealth] (minute.south) to[bend left] node[midway,below] {$\times 60$} (heure.south);
  \draw[-stealth,shorten >= 2pt] (seconde.south) to[bend left] node[midway,below] {$\times 60$} (minute.south);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, solved the problem by changing the draw command to the path command. If someone can explain the difference between those 2, it would be super appreciated, thanks

Comment: Good that you found a workaround. This is probably better as a remark at the end of  your original question given that you have now changed what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

One more solution:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, quotes}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\node (heure) {Heures};
\node[right=2cm of heure]   (minute)    {Minutes};
\node[right=2cm of minute]  (seconde)   {Secondes};
%
\draw[-stealth,shorten >=1mm, shorten <=1mm] 
    (heure.north)   edge [bend left,"$\times 60$"] (minute.north) 
    (minute.north)  edge [bend left,"$\times 60$"] (seconde.north)
    (minute.south)  edge [bend left,"$\times 60$"] (heure.south) 
    (seconde.south)  to  [bend left,"$\times 60$"] (minute.south);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

As you can see, in last path I use `to` instead `edge`. Also is employed `quotes` library for writing of edge labels.

[image]